# VBA variable and formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ABC As Integer
    ABC = [A1+(B2*C3)] 'Works fine

    Dim i as Long
    Dim XYZ As Integer
    For i = 1 to 100
    XYZ = [A & i +(B & (i + 1) * C & (i + 2))] 'Not working - how to resolve this?
    'Rest of VBA code
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `[]` is short hand for Application.Evaluate.  When you use variables you need to actually use `Application.Evaluate("")` and parse the string.  But it would be better just to do:  `XYZ = Range("A" & i) + (Range("B" & i + 1) * Range("C" & i + 1))`

Comment: Great, thank you!!

Comment: @harrymc Yes it should.  Done

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is short hand for `Application.Evaluate`  When using variables one need to use `Application.Evaluate("")` and parse the string:

```
XYZ = Application.Evaluate("A" & i & "+(B" & (i + 1) & "* C" & (i + 2) & ")")
```

But `Application.Evaluate` assumes the active sheet and a better use would be to use `Worksheet.Evaluate` to ensure the correct sheet is being used:

```
XYZ = WorkSheet("Sheet1").Evaluate("A" & i & "+(B" & (i + 1) & "* C" & (i + 2) & ")")
```

But in this case using Evaluate is slow.  Instead just use the Range object itself.

```
With Worksheet("Sheet1")
    XYZ = .Range("A" & i) + (.Range("B" & i + 1) * .Range("C" & i + 1))
End With
```